# Animated GIF doesn't display in WebView on Android 1.6

Tags: android, webview, animated-gif

I have a problem when trying to display a GIF animation inside of a `WebView`.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you post your code? GIF animation should work the same way as in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animated gifs are not supported, seems to be a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422).

Comment: Thanks.i follow your link and get the solution in comment of LatinSuD:
As a workaround, if you are using a custom WebView, you can do these 2 things together:

- Enable Javascript for the Webview (Eg: http://code.google.com/p/slidetypekeyboard/source/browse/trunk/src/com/latinsud/android/slidetypekeyboard/HelpActivity.java)

- Then use javascript to swap images (Eg: http://code.google.com/p/slidetypekeyboard/source/browse/trunk/assets/index.html)
Please note that this is not a solution for displaying GIFs.