# Show animated Gif image in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [[Android 1.6]How to display GIF animation on Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510377/android-1-6how-to-display-gif-animation-on-webview)

I have the Animated Gif image in res folder.I need to show that image in My application.But it shows the first frame of the image.How to use Gif images in Android ??

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510377).

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107998/displaying-animated-gif-using-animate-drawable-problems). Got the same question there, and I already drop an answer that you may want to try. :)