# Displaying Animated gif using animate drawable problems

Tags: android

I'm attempting to have my animated gif animate on loop with the following code but I'm not having any luck...

**JAVA**

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.load_img);
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.load_animation);

AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

frameAnimation.start();
```

**XML**

```
<animation-list android:oneshot="false" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/load_0000" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/load_0001" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/load_0002" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/load_0003" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/load_0004" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/load_0005" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/load_0006" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/load_0007" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/load_0008" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/load_0009" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Anyone have any idea as to why it isn't animating?

Answer (score 10):

Seems that I was experiencing the same problem, when I used whether it is  `setImageResource(R.drawable.load_animation)` or
`setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.load_animation)`, the image wasn't displaying.

then I try to put the code in my XML view file, with `android:background="@drawable/load_animation`
got the image showed, but still not animated, it was only displaying a static image.

then after googling around a while I found that `AnimationDrawable` can not work in `onCreate`
we can either put it in `onResume` or `onWindowsFocusChanged`. So here I try with this:

```
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)
    findViewById(R.id.img_loading).getBackground();
    if (hasFocus) {
        loadingAnimation.start();
    } 
    else {
        loadingAnimation.stop();
    }
}
```

finally it works, the gif both showed and animated!

Comment: Oh my God how long have I been trying to get this damn thing working... THANK YOU !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `setImageResource(R.drawable.load_animation)`, not `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.load_animation)`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use img.startxx(frameAnimation)