# Android Menu Item Icon .gif

Tags: android, animation, icons

Guys how do i set animated (.gif) icon in `MenuItem`?

May be its Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107998/displaying-animated-gif-using-animate-drawable-problems) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif) but they use `animation-list` and I use (.gif).

Is It possible to set animated gif as an icon?

Answer (score 1):

One way to load animated gif is to use WebView which is technically an embedded browser. But I doubt this suits your need to display an icon. Your best bet is split your gif into individual frames in png and put them together in animation-list like your links suggest. Or you can refer to the official page [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html).

Comment: Thanks i try your suggestion for now but ill wait for another answer! :) ty